# Projects tab missing in JFrog Artifactory UI

Tags: artifactory

We have Artifactory Pro license version 7.27.10. As an Admin we don't see the Projects tab in the UI. Do we need the Enterprise or Enterprise+ license?

Answer (score 2):

From Artifactory 7.17.4, Projects is enabled by default in the JFrog Platform for Enterprise and Enterprise+ subscriptions, as stated in the JFrog wiki page [HERE](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Projects#Projects-OnboardingProjectsinanUpgradedEnvironment)

That said, from Artifactory 7.31.10, the JFrog Projects feature is supported on all JFrog Subscriptions, as follows:

All JFrog subscription types can create up to three projects in parallel to JFrog supporting extended usage of 30 projects for Enterprise subscriptions, and 300 projects for Enterprise+ subscriptions.

For further read please refer to [HERE](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Projects#Projects-Overview)